# javascript JSON.parse throw Unexpected end of JSON input error

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, ajax

i have 2 file tst.html and tst.php

**tst.html** body is

```
<form> 
<input id="search" type="text" size="30" onkeyup="showresult(this.value)" >
<div id="suggest"></div>
</form>


<script>
function showresult(val){
    if(val.trim() == ""){

    }else{
        var xttp = new XMLHttpRequest() ;
        xttp.onreadystatechange = function () {

             var s = xttp.responseText ;           

            if(s.match("zerorow")){
                document.getElementById("suggest").innerHTML = "zero" ;
            }else {
                try {
                    window.alert(s) ;
                    var arr = JSON.parse(s) ;

                }
                catch(err) {
                    document.getElementById("suggest").innerHTML =  err.message;
                }



            }
        };
        xttp.open("POST" , "tst.php" ,true) ;
        xttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded") ;
        xttp.send("val="+val) ;
    }
}
```

and tst.php

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$dbusername = "mamad";
$dbpassword = "";
$dbname = "t1" ;

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $dbusername, $dbpassword , $dbname);

if (!$conn) {
die("Connection failedddddddddd: " . mysqli_connect_error());

}else{

$val = $_POST["val"] ;
$sql = "SELECT tag FROM tags WHERE tag LIKE '$val%'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if($result){
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
        $arr = mysqli_fetch_all($result , MYSQLI_NUM) ;
        echo json_encode($arr) ;
    }else{
        echo "zerorow" ;
    }
}else{
    echo die("faileddd " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

}
?>
```

assume in my database i have two record tag1 and tag2 in tag column 
and

```
$arr = mysqli_fetch_all($result , MYSQLI_NUM) ;
json_encode($arr) ;
```

if you input **t** alphabet in input field tst.php
pass a 2 dimensional array as string like this **[["tag1"],["tag2"]]**

but

```
var arr = JSON.parse(s) ;
```

throw a **syntax error** with **JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data** message

and one more question i just want want column of data of table in my database is there any function that do it and give one dimensional array ?

sorry if it become long question .

Comment: `onreadystatechange ` fires multiple times. you should test it the status is 200 and the readystate is OK.

Comment: There are multiple echoes, only one of them seem to actually echo valid JSON, the others just echo random strings. And as noted above, the event handler for the ajax request is wrong, and will fire on all readyStates

Comment: don't use `window.alert(s);` to look at your response. use the browser console. take a look at the length of this string and call trim() on it and check the length again. I'm pretty sure there are characters you missed that are prepend or append to the json string.

Comment: thanks i edited echo and thanaks for your suggest @Joshua K

Comment: it seems status checking  solved the problem if you make it as answe i can accept it as right solution , thanks i always did that but when you copy code frome different file it happne :D @adeneo

Comment: @ Joshua K but i use your suggestion in my way to learn programming in future my friend , thanks very much

Comment: i just saw i mentioned wrong guy  , i wanted to mentioned you ,it seems status checking solved the problem if you make it as answer i can accept it as right solution , thanks i always did that but when you copy code from different file it happnen :D @Joshua K

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `onreadystatechange` event fires on every state change, not only if the request is finished and the result is returned.

You have to add some checks to make it work:

- The `readyState` must be in status `DONE`, and
- the http status must be 200

In code that looks like this:

```
xttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if(xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE && xttp.status === 200) {
    var s = xttp.responseText ;           

    if(s.match("zerorow")){
      document.getElementById("suggest").innerHTML = "zero" ;
    } else {
      try {
        window.alert(s) ;
        var arr = JSON.parse(s) ;
      } catch(err) {
        document.getElementById("suggest").innerHTML =  err.message;
      }
    }
  }
};
```

*Hint: Better use only one return type. In your case JSON. In your code your mixing up different content types. That's bad style*

*Furthermore your sql is attackable with sql injections. This is an security and safty issue*